# How can I close a notebook tab in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs

The question is:

How can I close the tabs in tkinter.ttk `Notebook` widget? To make things simple,

```
def add_tab():
    global tab
    tab = Frame(notebook)
    notebook.add(tab, text=f'{"new.txt": ^20}')

def close_tab():
    tab.destroy()
```

However, when I execute this, the tab that is created most recently gets closed. The others do not get closed even when I click the button.

Moreover, how can I find which tab is currently opened and close that accordingly?

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `notebook.forget("current")` to remove the current selected tab:

```py
def close_tab():
    notebook.forget("current")
```